# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, teaspoon

This is not a duplicate because both provided related questions do not address why web drivers gem is not working to automatically update chrome, which is it's intended purpose. The solution proposed show to fix manually, I am looking for a permanent and automatic solution, which is the purpose of webdrivers gem.

---

I am getting the following error when running teaspoon on my rails app...

```
$ rake teaspoon
Set localhost 3000 as the default_url_option ----
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:49518
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:49518/teaspoon/default
rake aborted!
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

GEM FILE

```
group :development, :test do
  # For javascript tests
  gem "teaspoon-jasmine"
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'  
end
```

I thought webdrivers was supposed to update my chrome driver, but it does not seem to be doing that. I am not sure if I need additional setup.

My goal is not to manually update this once, but have webdrivers gem work as expected and update the drivers when teaspoon tests are run.

https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon#installation

https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers

SOLUTION:

I had to run the test in the test environment to get it working..

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake teaspoon
```